# Repetición en la obtención de datos

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

*Buenas, estoy tratando de traer los datos de la siguiente página: [Página](https://lectortmo.com/library/manhwa/41512/solo-leveling). Quiero cargar en mi `RecyclerView` el número de capítulo (en este caso hay 121 capítulos) y la `url`. Pero, no he podido lograrlo del todo bien.

Este es el código del `Body` de la página al momento de realizar la búsqueda (lo simplifiqué para que solo se vea el `li` del capítulo 120 pero hay más `li` debajo de ese):

```
<li class="list-group-item p-0 bg-light upload-link" data-index="0">
<h4 class="px-2 py-3 m-0">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-10 text-truncate">
<a style="display: block;" class="btn-collapse" onclick="collapseChapter('collapsible490362')" role="button"> Capítulo 120.00</a>
</div>
</div>
</h4>
<div style="display: block;" id="collapsible490362">
<hr class="mx-0 my-1">
<div class="card chapter-list-element">
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush chapter-list">
<li class="list-group-item">
<div class="row"><div class="col-2 col-sm-1 text-right">
<a href="https://lectortmo.com/view_uploads/599487" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<span class="fas fa-play fa-2x" style="color:#2957ba"></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

El dato que quiero es el que dice:

```
Capítulo 120.00
```

Y así es como estoy parseando los datos:

```
@Override
    protected ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");

        tmoDatosSeleccions.clear();
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("div.row>.col-10.text-truncate");
            Elements dataDos = doc.select("div.col-2.col-sm-1.text-right");
            for (Element e1 : data) {
                String numeroCap = e1.select("a").html();
                numeroCap = numeroCap.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
                for(Element e2 : dataDos){
                    String urlManga = e2.select("a").attr("href");
                    tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlManga));
                }
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmoDatosSeleccions;
    }
```

¿Alguien me podría decir como puedo hacerlo de manera correcta? Ya que al momento de vizualizar el dato en el `TextView` este se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y se tendría que ver **Capítulo 120.00**, abajo **Capítulo 119.00** etc

Comment: Esa página debe obtener esos datos de algún API REST, te recomiendo hacer click secundario en la pagina y seleccionar "view page source". Así podrías encontrar el origen de los datos y hacer la petición tú también.

Comment: ¿Puedes ver el error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Elements data = doc.select("li.list-group-item.p-0.bg-light.upload-link");
                Log.d("items", "total: " + data.size());
                for (Element e1 : data) {
                    String numeroCap = "";
                    String urlMan = "";
                    if(e1.select("div.col-10.text-truncate").size() > 0){
                        numeroCap = e1.select("a").get(0).text();
                        numeroCap = numeroCap.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
                        if(e1.select("div.col-2.col-sm-1.text-right").size() > 0 ){
                            urlMan = e1.select("a.btn.btn-default.btn-sm").get(0).attr("href");
                            if(urlMan.contains("/paginated")){
                                urlMan.replace("/paginated", "/cascade");
                                tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlMan));
                            }else{
                                tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlMan));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```